# How to navigate to 3rd page from 2nd page in NavigationPane

Tags: xml, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have 3 pages with a BlackBerry 10 project

The first page is a navigation pane that contains a page with a list
The second page is Page that contains a list
The third page is another Page containing a different list

I want to be able to tap an item within my list on the second page so that it takes me to the third page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach page in second QML

```
attachedObjects: [
     ComponentDefinition {
         id: thirdPage
         source: thirdPage.qml
     }
]
```

And open it

```
//assuming NavigationPane in first QML has id navigationPane
navigationPane.push(thirdPage.createObject()); //assuming NavigationPane in
```

Why will this work? Because second QML still has access to first page, or at least its NavigationPane

Comment: The list in my second page contains a dozen items each with a property called 'file' and contains their own qml url e.g. "lines_and_stations/Bakerloo/Bakerloo_line.qml". Is there any chance I could email you my BB10 project?

Comment: Why so many files? If you have just images/text you can set them.

Comment: I need these files as they are necessary for my project. What do you mean by set them? Did you mean send?

Comment: You don't need so many files. You can set all information dynamically on one QML only